# AWS ECS Cluster with Container instance IAM role by CloudFormation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation, amazon-ecs

I am trying to write a complete CloudFormation stack where the **ECS Cluster** will connect to an **AutoScaling Group** (*via a CapacityProvider*), which is connected to a LaunchTemplate. I've attached an **EC2 Instance role**.

Now all services are working except in ECS Cluster >> ECS Instances, I can't see the instances.

[image]

I believe if I can attach the same EC2 Instance role in ECS Cluster, the instances will appear here, as it do when I set it up manually.

*Container Instance IAM Role while manually setup ECS Cluster*
[image: Container Instance IAM Role while manually setup ECS Cluster]

**Problem**

I can't find any [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-ecs-cluster.html) or example to attach the EC2 Instance Profile/Role with ECS Cluster. Hense my services are not able to provision any Task.

Is my approach wrong or I am missing something?

Comment: What is the UserData of your cluster instances as defined in your launch template? Also can you show how you defined the ecsInstanceRole in your cloudforamtion?

Comment: @Marcin right now, no UserData is set. Later I'll add TaskDefinitions and Services in ECS to launch the cluster. `ecsInstanceRole` is an existing role with proper permissions. This role is used in another cluster which is already running and working.